# Cron does not run if screen is off?

Tags: cron

On Ubuntu 20.04 Server on a Dell Laptop. I've scheduled a simple cron job to run a Python script at 4am. It does not run, but if I schedule for another time (say 11am)--usually (maybe always) when the screen is on, it runs fine. Help me troubleshoot this.

I was redirected from Stack Overflow to here. I am at my wits end here. I've spent weeks trying various search terms but can't seem to find my specific issue.

I've tried a lot of things:

- Script works fine and executes normally (This is not a syntax issue)
- Turned off sleep mode on the computer (thinking it was a display issue)
- Screen still turns off, but does not lock or suspend; maybe still a display issue?
- Added (then removed) display=:0 because it didn't change anything, so maybe not a display issue?
- Uninstalled anacron to guarantee that only cron would dictate schedule
- I also have a small Python script that executes every hour to test that cron is working.

Weird hints that might help:

- When I run the command `grep cron /var/log/syslog` in terminal it has either one of two behaviors

  - it shows a log that starts only around the time that I open the laptop lid.
  - nothing happens. This tends to occur when I open the machine in the mornings. Again, it does not turn off, lock, or suspend. Only the screen turns off.
- Looking at `systemctl status cron` the service appears to have only logged events when my screen is awake.

Is it possible that Ubuntu is suspending the cron daemon (and likely other services) when I close my lid? If so, how can I prevent that from happening or what config areas should I look into?

Comment: Sounds like if the screen if off the machine is in suspend, hence no processing.

Comment: I've explicitly prevented the system from suspending in the power settings. I'm inclined to agree with you from a behavior perspective, yet no settings I've found lead me to that conclusion. Any pointers on where I can further search to see if the computer switches to a suspend-like state when I close the lid?

Comment: Look in /var/log/syslog to see what the system is doing when you open/close the lid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came back around and looked at what was happening on the system using `grep sleep /var/log/syslog`

It looks like even though sleep and suspend settings had been turned off, another service was putting the system into a suspend state.

I used this [article](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-suspend-and-hibernation-in-linux/) to resolve the issue.

The issue seems to be resolved BUT I'm now having trouble with the touchpad. A minor issue overall if the computer continues to work as expected.